# Using snapshot to get data from firebase - error: "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'."

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use `UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)` to get the user informations. In this case uid, username, email etc.

I try to get the user uid with `snapshot.data()[UID];`. I already tried to use `snapshot.data()['uid'];` and `snapshot.data['uid'];` too, but without success.

What I am doing wrong? I tried to google it, but I can't find any mistake in `snapshot.data['uid'];`

**error message:**

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
```

**Edit:**

when i downgrade my pubspec.yaml then it is actually working:
`firebase_auth: ^0.18.3+1   firebase_core: ^0.5.2+1   cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3+1`

But how can I get this code working with the newest version? I prefere to use the newest version:
`firebase_auth: ^3.3.19  firebase_core: ^1.17.1  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.13`

**code:**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserModel {
  final String UID = "uid";
  final String USERNAME = "username";
  final String EMAIL = "email";
  final String FIRSTNAME = "first name";
  final String LASTNAME = "last name";
  final String BIRTHDAY = "birthday";
  final String GENDER = "gender";


  String _uid;
  String _username;
  String _email;
  String _firstName;
  String _lastName;
  String _birthday;
  String _gender;

//  getters
  String get uid => _uid;
  String get username => _username;
  String get email => _email;
  String get firstName => _firstName;
  String get lastName => _lastName;
  String get birthday => _birthday;
  String get gender => _gender;


  //snapshot.data.data() as Map<String,dynamic>;

  UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    _uid = snapshot.data()[UID];
    _username = snapshot.data()[USERNAME];
    _email = snapshot.data()[EMAIL];
    _firstName = snapshot.data()[FIRSTNAME];
    _lastName = snapshot.data()[LASTNAME];
    _birthday = snapshot.data()[BIRTHDAY];
    _gender = snapshot.data()[GENDER];

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is, that the older version returns a map <String, dynamic> and the latest version returns an object.

So for using the latest version I need to create a Map <String, dynamic> and paste snapshot.data() in there.
Problem solved.

```
UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data() as Map<String,dynamic>;
    _uid = data[UID];
    _username = data[USERNAME];
    _email = data[EMAIL];
    _firstName = data[FIRSTNAME];
    _lastName = data[LASTNAME];
    _birthday = data[BIRTHDAY];
    _gender = data[GENDER];
  }
```